# Regex "Url" outside comments

Tags: regex

would like to match urls which are **outside** the comment function from javascript.

Regex for Url's:

```
((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)
```

given this example:

```
/* http://goog.le */
http://goog.le
```

it should only match the second.

i tried [here](http://regexpal.com/) so far with this regex without success:

```
(/*)[^(*/)]*((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)
```

thanks for advise

Comment: Wouldn't only matching inside strings be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's hard (but certainly not impossible) to do this sort of parsing with regex - you have to make assumptions such as the input is well-formed.

First note that in your regex the `{1}` is redundant so that can be removed.

You can do something like the following, which matches the URL only if it's *not* followed by a `*/` (with no matching `/*`). The logic is that if it *is* followed by `*/`, it's probably in a comment:

```
((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)(?!([^*/]|\*[^/]|/[^*])*\*/)
```

Of course, this will fail if you have `*/` in the source without having a matching `/*`, e.g.

```
/* http://goog.le */ # this won't match
http://goog.le       # this will match
http://google/ "*/fdsa" # this won't match!
```

I think any regex approach you take will in some way rely on the input being well-formed -- comments are balanced, etc.

(If you are using javascript, is it possible to use some sort of XML parsing instead? This works *much* better and will probably allow you to ignore comments in any case).

Comment: Oh I knew I was forgetting somethin - will update the regex. cheers.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee +1 thx for a working regex, the explanation of the limitation and the xml suggestion which i will try to consider for a broader approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a replace and do things like http://jsfiddle.net/92ma8/ which will work for strings and escapes.

```
// remove comments
// if you want to remove single line comments as well add: |\/\/.*
var nocomments = code.replace(/("(?:[^"\\]*|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]*|\\.)*')|\/\*[^]*?\*\//g, "$1");

// do your matching
var result = nocomments.match(/[a-z]+:\/\/\S+/gi);
```

In this string:

```
/* http://aaa.com */               
http://bbb.com                     
//  http://ccc.com                 
http://ddd.com "will \"*/ /*work" 
"/* http://eee.com */ works"
```

It matches:

```
http://bbb.com
http://ccc.com
http://ddd.com
http://eee.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((?<!\/\*)) #Negative lookbehind
  ((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)(?!([^*]|\*[^/])*\*/)
(
  ?(1) # Ensure the negative lookbehind has matched (Embedded Condition)
  (?!\*/) # Ensure the negative lookahead
)
```

Here's the one liner

```
((?<!\/\*))((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)(?!([^*]|\*[^/])*\*/)(?(1)(?!\*/))
```

Comment: @Panuccio it doesn't match the url's.

Comment: I used RegexBuddy to test this using the .NET engine and it worked fine. I simply used your regex to match the URL so perhaps that part isn't matching what you expect. For the "http://goog.le" example you gave in your question it works.